# Haskell: Monad return list

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to write some code in Haskell and there is problem that i can't solve

```
f 0 = []
f n = do
    x <- [0..4]
    y <- x:(f (n-1))
    return y
```

The output is:

```
[0,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,0,1,2,3,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,2,0,1,2,3,4,3,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,1,2,3,4]
```

but I need it to be:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4],[0,1,0],[0,1,1]...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Others have already answered, but you may wish to know there's already a function like yours in the standard library:

```
> import Control.Monad
> replicateM 3 [0..4]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4],[0,1,0],[0,1,1], ...
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want the elements of your final list to be lists themselves ?

In the List monad, each `<-` remove one enclosing from the type, in other words :

`(x :: a) <- (xs :: [a])`

So it is clear that `x :: Int` in your code. And you wish for your function to return `[[Int]]` so what should be the type of `x:(f (n-1))` ? You see that this expression shouldn't typecheck if `f` type was correct so there is your problem : you don't want to cons `x` to the result of `f (n-1)` but to each of the results of `f (n-1)` thus :

```
f n = do
  x <- [0..4]
  xs <- f (n-1)
  return (x : xs)
```

If you try this you should see it doesn't work, this is because your `f 0` should contain one possibility :

```
f 0 = return [] -- or [[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's desugar first:

```
f 0 = []
f n = [0 .. 4] >>= \x -> x : (f (n - 1)) >>= \y -> return y
```

Note

```
xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

`[0..4] >>= \x -> x : (f (n - 1))` will simply return `[0..4]` when n is 1. However, it need to be `[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`,

Thus, the following will do:

```
f 0 = [[]]
f n = [0 .. 4] >>= \x -> map (x:) (f (n - 1)) >>= \y -> return y
```

Comment: The final `>>= \y -> return y` can be omitted, according to the monad laws.

Answer (score 0):

```
cross = do
x <- [0..4]
y <- [0..4]
z <- [0..4]
return [x,y,z]
```

Comment: What does this add to chi's answer?